# Set turrent client to automatically start downloading a torrent when it's available

Tags: transmission

It's tedious to continue checking  for a movie until it has a torrent. Is there a plug in (for transmission) that will save my "wanted" list and look for my movies automatically?

And notify me when I can download it ?

Comment: You can say to transmission to monitor a folder and you drop there the torrent file

Answer (score 1):

I use [flexget](http://flexget.com/) for downloading automatically. Mostly series so I use it daily. You can filter on quality, subgroup and many many more. It even has IMDB filtering.

> **Daemon Mode**
>
> You can now run FlexGet in daemon mode, and handle scheduling directly in your FlexGet config. Traditional cron scheduling is also supported.
>
> **Torrent clients**
>
> Integrates with Deluge, transmission, and uTorrent directly, and other clients like rTorrent via watchdirs.
>
> **Movies**
>
> Internal movie queue. Automatic searching. Grab all movies which match predefined imdb and/or rotten tomatoes rules (score, year, etc).

---

Downside: it uses a text file you need to create and maintain so you will need to know upfront the movie name if you want to creaste a list of future downloads. Example from the link:

```
tasks:
  task name:
    rss: http://example.com/torrents.xml
    series:
      - pioneer one
      - some series
    download: ~/torrents/series/
```

This would downloade new episodes of serie "pioneer one" and "some series" the moment the torrent is active on "http://example.com/torrents.xml" and it will download the file to "~/torrents/series/". A configuration can become very complex and very large rather quickly.

---

- [Cookbook](http://flexget.com/wiki/Cookbook) and [Configuration examples](http://flexget.com/wiki/Configuration).
- [Plugins](http://flexget.com/wiki/Plugins)

Answer (score 1):

It just happens that I've made an easy to use Python application for downloading YIFY movies (**only**), either the ones already available, or the ones that you are expecting to be available soon.

The application can be found on GitHub: https://github.com/hakermania/autoYIFY/ . You can click the 'Download ZIP' button on the right to download it.

On the above page you can find a pretty good documentation about it, but I will break down the main things here (I suggest reading the documentation though because it keeps it simple and clear and shows all the available potentially useful options):

1. Install the dependencies:

   `sudo apt-get install python-bs4`
2. Make the program executable and run it once to let it create the configuration files. Terminate it with **Ctrl+C** after it complains about having no movies to search for.

   `chmod +x autoYIFY.py; ./autoYIFY.py`
3. Make the program accessible by typing just the command `yify`. There are multiple ways of doing this, I prefer creating a soft link:

   `sudo ln -s /home/alex/Documents/Scripts/autoYIFY.py /usr/bin/yify`

Before running the above command, change the `autoYIFY.py` path to the permanent path of your `autoYIFY.py` script.

4. Set the configuration options in the file `~/.autoYIFY/settings`

There are some options that you can set, like `check-interval` which is the interval between each check for movie availability. More options can be found on the documentation, on the link I posted above.

5. Use the program.

   - Download movie right now:

   `yify 'Movie Name'`

   - Download subtitle right now:

   `yify sub 'language name' 'Movie Name'`

   - **Wait for movies to become available**:

   `yify`

Notice that you run it without any arguments. You just have to list your movies (one per line) at `~/.autoYIFY/loop-movies`, then you just run it and it will wait until they become available. Once a movie becomes available, it will be automatically removed from `~/.autoYIFY/loop-movies` (and launched in your torrent client).

I suggest you put the `yify` command at the startup so as you don't have to worry about starting it each time you open your computer.

Comment: Cool! Bookmarked and will try this out this weekend :D

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [couchpotato](https://couchpota.to/) for movies (and [sickbeard](http://sickbeard.com/) for series).

- It support torrents via various search engines, but also newsgroups.
- It supports various download actions, you can choose your downloader (e.g. by putting the file in a certain directory)
- for series, sickbeard can 'follow' your seasons
- it has post-download options to move, rename etc.

Answer (score 0):

Integrated with Transmission, no, at least nothing that you can obtain OOTB. You can set up a RSS client that downloads torrents into a directory and make Transmission to load automatically all torrents in such directory, like the [transmission-rss](https://github.com/nning/transmission-rss) project do. That's the only way of using Transmission + something lightweight.

A more integrated solution is using instead [Deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org/) and [YaRSS2 plugin](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Plugins/YaRSS2).

Comment: YaRSS2 plugin isn't working. tried to install it bug nothing happened. using ubuntu 14.10 with python 2.7.8

Comment: @yehudahs that seems to deserve a [new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask?tags=deluge) with more information, as, did you followed the instructions, what you have done, etc. not something to fix in comments.